# nginx configuration to provide dynamic error pages

Tags: reactjs, nginx, custom-error-pages, nginx-config

I have an nginx server setup that serves as is used to for proxy and serving static content.
The static contents are based on multiple react apps.
What I want to do is replace the default error pages from nginx and serve the error pages from a React App.

The React app handles error pages based on the url. `http://localhost/401.html` will provide the standard 401 HTTP error page for the app, and so on. The problem is how to correctly configure this in nginx, because in reality there is no `401.html` page. There is just one html file and that is `index.html'. React app handles that all own its own based on the URL using React Router.

I have tried with some `error_page` configuration with nginx with no luck.

Here is how the error page configuration looks like:
```

```
error_page 400 /error/400.html;
error_page 401 /error/401.html;
error_page 402 /error/402.html;
error_page 403 /error/403.html;
error_page 404 /error/404.html;
error_page 405 /error/405.html;
error_page 406 /error/406.html;
error_page 407 /error/407.html;
error_page 408 /error/408.html;
error_page 409 /error/409.html;
error_page 410 /error/410.html;
error_page 411 /error/411.html;
error_page 412 /error/412.html;
error_page 413 /error/413.html;
error_page 414 /error/414.html;
error_page 415 /error/415.html;
error_page 416 /error/416.html;
error_page 417 /error/417.html;
error_page 418 /error/418.html;
error_page 422 /error/422.html;
error_page 423 /error/423.html;
error_page 424 /error/424.html;
error_page 426 /error/426.html;
error_page 428 /error/428.html;
error_page 429 /error/429.html;
error_page 431 /error/431.html;
error_page 451 /error/451.html;
# 50x errors
error_page 500 /error/500.html;
error_page 501 /error/501.html;
error_page 502 /error/502.html;
error_page 503 /error/503.html;
error_page 504 /error/504.html;
error_page 505 /error/505.html;
error_page 506 /error/506.html;
error_page 507 /error/507.html;
error_page 511 /error/511.html;

location ^~ /error/ {
  root /usr/local/var/www/html/;
  allow all;
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}
```

```

And this is how I include it in my `nginx.conf`:

```
    server {
         listen       8443 ssl;
         server_name  localhost;



    ssl_certificate      domain.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  domain.key;

    ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

    ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

    if ( $http_user_agent ~* (nmap|nikto|wikto|sf|sqlmap|bsqlbf|w3af|acunetix|havij|appscan) ) {
        return 444;
    }


    location / {
        proxy_pass   http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_http_version      1.1;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For    $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        Host         $server_name:$server_port;
        proxy_set_header        Upgrade            $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header        Connection         $connection_upgrade;
    }

    include error-pages/error_pages.conf;


    location /backend/ {
        proxy_pass   https://localhost:8181/backend/;
        proxy_intercept_errors on;
    }

}
```

Is it possible to serve error pages like this in nginx? Because it still gives me the standard 404 not found error page from nginx, because i think it is trying to find the `401.html` page in that folder.

Comment: `I have tried with some error_page`, what happened ?

Comment: @KedarnagMukanahallipatna The configuration is used for `error_page` is above. It returns the default 404 error from nginx. even when i want to access those pages by specifying the path in the browser

Answer (score 0):

Why not do something like this ? Assuming you have an error directory.

```
error_page 403 /error/403.html;
error_page 404 /error/404.html;
error_page 405 /error/405.html;
error_page 500 501 502 503 504 /error/5xx.html;

location ^~ /error/ {
    internal;
    root /var/www/default;
}
```

You can use this as [reference](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#error_page)

Comment: Does not work. I tried this already and it still shows me the nginx error page